# Parent div not wrapping image inside it

Tags: html, css

i'm working with a website.i have a problem with the divs

```
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child" style="display:inline-block; z-ndex:1000;">
        <img src="" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

html:

```
   .parent {
       clear: both;
       float: left;
       padding:0 2%;
       width: 98%;
       padding:0 1%;
       display: block;
       height:557px;
   }
```

I have my html like this, i want my child div to wrap around the image so i gave it inline-block. but if the image is large, i'm getting the image out of the parent div.
Is there any way that it get fixed in the parent div.
Any help please .

Comment: can you provide the screen shot too please

Comment: i cant post images here ..they dont allow me ;) @WillyLazuardi

Comment: why did you set `height` attribute to `.parent`? it makes your parent div's height fixed & couldn't be scaled by the image right?

Comment: Actually everything works perfect for me, i have setup a fiddle for you, let me know is there any problem in this. [FIDDLE>>](http://jsfiddle.net/TQzGL/)

Comment: I want my parent div to be fixed..@WillyLazuardi

Comment: @PrasanthKC it works fine in the fiddle...but the image is not fixed in the div if its large

Comment: @Vidia large means?? the image i have given there is also a large one, but `max-width` makes it smaller, check by removing `max-width` from style in fiddle.

Comment: @Vidia really what you want to fix?? do you want your `parent` div wrap the `image` fully even if image width is larger?? or you want to make image smaller to fit the `parent` div

Comment: if i remove max-width and max-height , the image is same as before. its not fixed in the parent div..

Comment: i want the child div to wrap around the image..and fit to the parent div..even if the image is large..

Comment: @Vidia then remove the `width:98%` from your css. So that it will wrap the image even if it is larger

Comment: your child div comes out of parent div with `z-index:1000!`

Comment: for a note: there is a typo in your `z-index`. You have written `z-ndex` instead of `z-index`

Comment: @Vidia As you have applied z-index and all, I assume you have some other css for child and all. provide it here if so.

Answer (score 4):

you should set some style attributes .i.e. height and width of outer[parent] div so that contents get bounded by it.

```
      <div class="parent" style="height: 80px; width: 80px;">
        <div class="child" style="display:inline-block;">
          <img src="" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set some height and width to your parent and Child Div.

Sample code which has image size larger than parent Div

```
<div class="parent" style="background-color: pink; height: 100px; width: 100px;">
      <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: black; height: 80px; width: 80px;" class="child">
        <img style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%" src="../somepath.JPG">
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the child div's height & width should be dynamic according the image size. shouldn't it?

Comment: i'm not giving any fixed ht to the child div, i just want it to wrap around my image ..and fix into my parent div..is that possible?

Comment: Then youcan set child Div height:100% and Width:100%. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I want my child divs h/w to be same as my image.. @Kishori

Comment: That can be achieved by setting h/w as auto but you have given some height and width to your parent Div. so If the image size is has bigger size then definitely it will overflow.

Comment: is there anyway that it gets fixed?

Comment: You can either maintain size of parent same and cut the image according to parent h/w. or image will overflow out of parent box whenever it is large. which one would you prefer?

Comment: @Vidia your current code does so. your `.child` has width and height same as image. check the fiddle i have setup for you [FIDDLE>>](http://jsfiddle.net/TQzGL/)

Comment: @Kishori no other way to fix it

Comment: You can set height:inherit and width:auto. this will adjust image in parent div or set overflow:scroll to parent class which will scroll the parent Div depending on image size.

Answer (score 0):

Mention the fixed `height` and `width` in `pixel` to parent `DIV` .Image will fix in the parent `DIV`

Take a look [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/VXtwV/). Actually image size `200*200` px ,parent DIV size `100*100` px .Now it will fix

**HTML :**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="display:inline-block; z-ndex:1000;">
    <img src="http://www.jonathanjeter.com/images/Square_200x200.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.parent 
      {
       clear: both;
       float: left;
       padding:0 2%;
       width: 100px;
       padding:0 1%;
       display: block;
       height: 100px;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now your `.parent` div has `width:98%`, As it is in `%` the div will attain a width `98%` of the current viewport or browser window you used to view the site irrespective of the content inside..

So even if your image inside `.parent` div is larger, `div` will get only the `98%` of window.

**1.) if you want your image in its original size and the parent should wrapped around**, you can go with this:

remove `width:98%` from `.parent` and remove `max-width` from image.

**2.) If you are looking to resize the image with respect to the width attained by `.parent`**

You can use the same code you are using now.